# MySQL - How can you select multiple columns on a nested IFNULL...GROUP_CONCAT() condition?

Tags: mysql

I have a web application which is connected to a MySQL (5.5.64-MariaDB) database.

One of the queries is as follows:

```
SELECT 
        d.id, 
        d.label AS display_label, 
        d.anchor, 
        r.id AS regulation_id, 
        IFNULL(
            (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(value) FROM display_substances `ds` 
              WHERE `ds`.`display_id` = `d`.`id`
              AND ds.substance_id = 1 -- For example, substance ID = 1 
              GROUP BY `ds`.`display_id`
            ), "Not Listed"
        ) `display_value` FROM displays `d`
        JOIN groups g ON d.group_id = g.id
        JOIN regulations r ON g.regulation_id = r.id
```

An example of the output is as follows:

```
+-----+------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id  | name                               | display_value                                                                            |
+-----+------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   4 | techfunction                       | Intermediate / monomer;  Corrosion inhibitor / anodiser / galvaniser; Catalyst; Additive |
| 323 | russia_chemsafety_register_display | Not Listed                                                                               |
| 733 | peru_pcb_display                   | Not Listed                                                                               |
+-----+------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This query does what we need. For explanatory purposes:

1. There are 2 tables, `displays` and `display_substances`
2. The query is obtaining `display_substances.value` for each `displays.id`
3. If there is no corresponding `display_substances.value` then the string "Not Listed" (refer to query above) is returned. If there *is* a corresponding value then `display_substances.value` is returned. So in the example data above, IDs `323` and `733` refer to a scenario where there is no corresponding entry, therefore we want "Not Listed". Conversely ID `4` does have a value ("Intermediate / monomer;  Corrosion inhibitor / anodiser / galvaniser; Catalyst; Additive") so we get that.

The table structures are as follows:

```
DESCRIBE displays;
+----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name     | varchar(127)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| label    | varchar(255)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


DESCRIBE display_substances;
+--------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| display_id   | smallint(5) unsigned  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| substance_id | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| value        | text                  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| automated    | tinyint(4)            | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
+--------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I want to be able to return `display_substances.automated` (refer to table structure above) as a column from my query. But I can't see how to do this.

The reference to the `display_substances` table is `ds`, so I cannot use that in the initial `SELECT` statement because at that point there's no alias. Equally there is no `JOIN` condition that would make it possible, because not every row returned obtains data from `display_substances` (i.e. those that are "Not Listed" are not getting anything from that table).

If I want an additional column next to `display_value` in the sample output above that shows `display_substances.automated`, or `NULL` if it doesn't exist, how can I achieve that?

For reference the `automated` field either contains a 1 (to represent data that has been obtained through automated processes by our application), or `NULL` if it isn't automated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> there is no JOIN condition that would make it possible, because not
> every row returned obtains data from display_substances

For this case you can use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT d.id, d.label display_label, d.anchor, r.id regulation_id, 
  COALESCE(ds.value, 'Not Listed') display_value,
  ds.automated     
FROM displays d
INNER JOIN groups g ON d.group_id = g.id
INNER JOIN regulations r ON g.regulation_id = r.id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT display_id, GROUP_CONCAT(value) value, MAX(automated) automated     
  FROM display_substances  
  WHERE substance_id = 1
  GROUP BY display_id
) ds ON ds.display_id = d.id
```

I used `MAX(automated)` as the returned column, but you can use `GROUP_CONCAT(automated)` just like you do for `value` and also `COALESCE()`:

```
COALESCE(ds.automated, 'Not Listed')
```

Comment: That doesn't execute. It gives an SQL error, `Unknown column 'ds.display_id' in 'on clause'`

Comment: Correct, I missed display_id in the select list. I edited.